# Potiential data loss with using InMemoryMessageDataRepository in production with MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

We are hoping to convert to mass transit, but due to the size of the data we need to store in the message data repository, we are needing to keep it in memory. The data is sometimes over 15GB, and the SQL query to fetch it takes up to 300 seconds. We don't want to have to fetch the data potentially 100s of times (which is how the consumers would be logically broken up). We need to continue to fetch it from sql once and keep it in memory, or performance will be crippled. We would ultimately like to stop needing to have so much data in memory, but it is not something we could feasibly fix in the short term. We are hoping to convert to mass transit now though, as we see significant benefits in doing so, and the InMemoryMessageDataRepository seems like the only path that would allow us to do this right now. However, the documentation says only to use that for unit testing.

I am trying to find out if this is something we can use in production code. What are the pitfalls in using the InMemoryMessageDataRepository in production? I can't find much about this, other than this blog post, https://kevsoft.net/2017/05/18/transferring-big-payloads-with-masstransit-and-azure-blob-storage.html,  which says

> It is however advised not to use in-memory storage due to potential data loss.

Why would there be potential data loss? What is mass transit doing with the InMemoryMessageDataRepository that would make using it in production risky?

Comment: Well, it's in-memory. If the process dies, it's all gone.

Comment: Gotcha, so we'd be in the same place we are today. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't any sort of clearing of the datastore, out of some expectation that it would be persisted more permanently. Thanks for answering!